# ¿Cómo puedo añadir saltos de línea en un JTable?

Tags: java, jtable

tengo una función que genera el modelo de mi tabla, los datos de la tabla constan de un String y una foto, ambos los saco de una base de datos en MYSQL, mi problema es que al momento de mostrar el string, este la muestra en una sola línea, me gustaría que este se muestre con salto de líneas como si fuera un TextArea, aquí dejo una parte del código:

```
 public void MTabla(JTable tabla) throws SQLException, IOException {
    tabla.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new Render());
    
    DefaultTableModel dt;
    dt = new DefaultTableModel() {
        
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;
        }
    };
    dt.addColumn("DESCRIPCIÓN");
    dt.addColumn("FOTO");
    
    busquedaTabla bu = new busquedaTabla();
    SGhabitación sg = new SGhabitación();
    
    ArrayList<SGhabitación> list = bu.Lista_habitaciones();
    
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println(list.size() + "  Tipos de habitaciones distintas");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Object fila[] = new Object[3];
            sg = list.get(i);
            
            fila[0] = sg.getDescripción();
            try {
                byte[] bi = sg.getFoto();
                
                BufferedImage image = null;
                InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bi);
                image = ImageIO.read(in);
                imgi = new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(320, 240, 0));
                fila[1] = new JLabel(imgi);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error al cargar la imagen: " + ex);
                fila[1] = new JLabel("NO IMAGEN");
            }
            dt.addRow(fila);
            
        }
        tabla.setModel(dt);
        tabla.setRowHeight(300);
    }
    
}
```

Y este es el resultado que obtengo:

[image: EJEMPLO:]

También he intentado introducir un TextArea directamente a la tabla, lo intente de la siguiente manera:

```
public void MTabla(JTable tabla) throws SQLException, IOException {
    tabla.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new Render());
    
    DefaultTableModel dt;
    dt = new DefaultTableModel() {
        
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;
        }
    };
    dt.addColumn("DESCRIPCIÓN");
    dt.addColumn("FOTO");
    
    busquedaTabla bu = new busquedaTabla();
    SGhabitación sg = new SGhabitación();
    
    ArrayList<SGhabitación> list = bu.Lista_habitaciones();
    
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println(list.size() + "  Tipos de habitaciones distintas");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Object fila[] = new Object[3];
            sg = list.get(i);
            
            JTextArea des = new JTextArea();
            des.setText(sg.getDescripción());
            
            fila[0] = des;
            try {
                byte[] bi = sg.getFoto();
                
                BufferedImage image = null;
                InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bi);
                image = ImageIO.read(in);
                imgi = new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(320, 240, 0));
                fila[1] = new JLabel(imgi);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error al cargar la imagen: " + ex);
                fila[1] = new JLabel("NO IMAGEN");
            }
            dt.addRow(fila);
            
        }
        tabla.setModel(dt);
        tabla.setRowHeight(300);
    }
    
}
```

Y me da el siguiente resultado:

[image: Ejemplo con textArea]

Agradecería mucho de su ayuda!.

Comment: Podrías añadir este método a tu textArea jTextArea.setLineWrap(true);, eso hará que el texto baje automáticamente cuando se quede sin espacio horizontalmente, también asegurate de que tenga un valor predefinido para que no termine por agrandarse y siga mostrando lo mismo.
Otra solución podría ser añadir manualmente saltos de línea a tu registro "\n" o reemplazar los puntos por saltos de linea.

Answer (score 0):

la solución fue añadir una función antes de mandar el String a la base de datos:

```
public String saltosDeLinea(String descripción) {
    String convertido = null;
    String sinSaltos = descripción.replaceAll("\n", "<br> ");
    convertido = "<HTML> " + sinSaltos + " </HTML>";
    return convertido;
}
```

De esta manera la función intercambia los saltos de línea por 
, lo mando a la base de datos, y cuando lo recupero dentro de la tabla; la tabla interpreta 
 como salto de línea.